# httpcookie from asp.net c# mvc application, not working on production server in chrome browser after server time change

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, cookies

I have created httpcookie from asp.net c# MVC application, which is working fine on the local system for all browsers. After uploading code on the server also it was working fine in all browser, but to test some scenario I change server time to future date and again I have reverted back to internet time. Just after this action chrome browser is not setting the cookie. It is showing under network panel in response header with correct value but when I explicitly try to check cookie value under all "cookies and site data" it is showing nothing. I have created the cookie using following code.

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Cook"];
        if (cookie != null)
        {
            cookie = new HttpCookie("Cook");
            cookie.Value = "Updated";
            cookie.Domain = "";
            cookie.Path = "/";
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            Response.SetCookie(cookie);
        }
        else
        {
            cookie = new HttpCookie("Cook");
            cookie.Value = "Added";
            cookie.Domain = "";
            cookie.Path = "/";
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
```

I am trying to fetch cookie value using

```
HttpCookie cookies = Request.Cookies["Cook"];
```

Here it shows null for chrome browser.
Also, the code is never going to if part as there is always null.

- Please note, that if I remove expiry at all, then it is working for all browser but closing browser is losing the cookie again
- Apart from this, I have also tried to set expiry for 3 days. In that case, it is even not working on the local system. Anyway, that is not my main concern, here I just want the cookie to be accessed in chrome with some expiry period(I am ok with even 1 year).
- This code is working fine till chrome version 24, I figured it out using this link https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=221359
- I tried to host it on another server, and the same code is working fine for all browsers on that server. Unfortunately, it is not working only on my production server.

Any help would be appreciated a lot!

Thanks